# "Undefined index: name" Laravel 5.7 Controller

Tags: php, laravel

I'm new to the blog and I joined because I have a problem for a while.

The following code is for importing users through a .csv file into a database, but when I try to import users, the following error appears.

```
8
"Undefined index: name"
"D:\xampp\htdocs\plataforma\app\Http\Controllers\UserController.php"
39
array:7 [▼
  "request" => Request {#43 ▶}
  "validator" => Validator {#257}
  "file" => UploadedFile {#247 ▶}
  "csvData" => """
    name,username,email,password,role,idSede,idManager\r\n
    Claudio Magallan,claudiomg,claudiomagallan@hotmail.com,secret,2,60,0\r\n
    Cristina Vargas,cristyvg,cristyvargas@institutodeventas.com,secret,3,61,4\r\n
    """
  "rows" => array:3 [▶]
  "header" => array:7 [▶]
  "row" => array:7 [▶]
]
```

I really appreciate your help and I hope you can help with my problem.
I attach my controller code.

```
public function upload(Request $request) {
  $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
    'file' => 'required'
  ]);
  if ($validator->fails()) {
    return redirect()
    ->back()
    ->withErrors($validator);
  }
  $file = $request->file('file');
  $csvData = file_get_contents($file);
  $rows = array_map("str_getcsv", explode("\n", $csvData));
  $header = array_shift($rows);
  foreach ($rows as $row) {
    $row = array_combine($header, $row);
    User::create([
      'name' => $row['name'],
      'username' => $row['username'],
      'email'    => $row['email'],
      'password' => bcrypt($row['password']),
      'role'     => $row['role'],
      'idSede'   => $row['idSede'],
      'idManager'=> $row['idManager'],
    ]);
  }
  flash('Users imported');
  return redirect()->back();
}
```

The error mark the next line code:

> 'name' => $row['name'],

Regards!

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: Hi Camilo, I try to import a list of users from a .csv file

Comment: What's the result of `dd($row)`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Notice: Undefined variable", "Notice: Undefined index", and "Notice: Undefined offset" using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/notice-undefined-variable-notice-undefined-index-and-notice-undefined)

Comment: Camilo... before the line $row = array_combine($header, $row); I get:
array:7 [▼
  0 => "Claudio Magallan"
  1 => "claudiomg"
  2 => "claudiomagallan@hotmail.com"
  3 => "secret"
  4 => "2"
  5 => "60"
  6 => "0"
]
after one I get:
array:7 [▼
  "name" => "Claudio Magallan"
  "username" => "claudiomg"
  "email" => "claudiomagallan@hotmail.com"
  "password" => "secret"
  "role" => "2"
  "idSede" => "60"
  "idManager" => "0"
]

Hi Miken, yeah looks similar but I used isset before but I didn't have a good result yet.

Comment: @AlanRincón attach your csv as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following change might work:

```
$rows = array_map("str_getcsv", explode("\n", $csvData));
$header = array_shift($rows);
array_pop($rows); // delete the element
foreach ($rows as $row) { .. }
```

---

Laravel can be easily debugged using `dump()` or `dd()`:

```
foreach ($rows as $row) {
    $row = array_combine($header, $row);
    dump($row); // print the current row for debugging.
    User::create([
      'name' => $row['name'],
      ...
    ]);
  }
```

This will produce something like:

```
    array(7) {
        ["name"]=> "Claudio Magallan"
        ....
    }

    array(7) {
        ["name"]=> "Cristina Vargas"
        ....
    }

    bool(false)
```

So the last line before the error is `false` and not an array. Just filter out this element.

If only the last line is garbage: use `array_pop($rows)` to delete the element of `$rows`. Or delete line break in last line of the CSV by hand. 
If more lines are garbage you can use `array_filter` to remove non compliant lines. E.g.:

```
$header = array_shift($rows);
$rows = array_filter($rows, function ($row) use ($header) {
    return count($row) === count($header);
});
foreach ($rows as $row) { .. }
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I was stuck in this 2 days. The array_pop function actually helps me to miss an invisible field to the final of my array and the dd function I never use it before and it helps me lot to see the function step by step.